# What makes Puzzles so Appealing?

Tags: puzzle-creation

What is so fascinating over a puzzle, why is it so much fun to solve? Especially a puzzle game, what makes it so fun to complete?

I want to make a puzzle game so I need a little bit of information on why they are so enjoyable.

Comment: Why the downvote, I'm clearly asking a question about puzzles, on a puzzling site?

Comment: If the question wasn't about puzzles, it would be closed for being off topic. I could see this being closed for being too broad, though. Downvotes, ultimately, mean "I don't like this". Why they don't like it is really their business, but I might guess they think it's very open-ended and maybe even academic. I think people on this site get the impression they're on a forum for sharing puzzles; they see a question like this and think "Boooring! Give me more puzzles!" Of course, this is just my guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"According to neuroscientist Daniel Bor, a research fellow at the University of Sussex in England and author of the new book The Ravenous Brain: How the New Science of Consciousness Explains Our Insatiable Search for Meaning, it’s because we take great pleasure in pattern-finding. What’s more, that conclusion has big implications for understanding the brain, consciousness and even neurological disorders like autism. We spoke with Bor recently.

Why do you call the brain “ravenous”?
Human brains have an extreme form of consciousness: they’re ravenous for new innovative solutions to problems in the world, ravenous for optimizing our lives, for building pyramids of knowledge. I was trying to capture [the sense of hunger that] extreme forms of consciousness have about searching for knowledge and for understanding."

From a Time magazine article "Why Solving Puzzles Is Fun: Q&A with Consciousness Researcher Daniel Bor"

There is more in the interview but most of it moves away from talking about puzzles.

As to why you were voted down I can't say - the site description says "Puzzling Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for those who study the creation and solving of puzzles. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about the creation and solving of puzzles."  It seems you are asking about "creation" and which would make it 'on topic'.  That being said, I don't see how understanding neuro-physiology is going to help with that task.

Perhaps, "What makes some puzzles more fun than others?" is what you were really after.

Comment: Pattern finding, interesting. Also "What makes puzzles more fun for others" would be too opinion based.

Comment: If there were research on what type of puzzles people prefer then it wouldn't necessarily be based on opinion...
Take a look at these articles: http://rpgmaker.net/articles/700/ and
http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/5667/what-makes-puzzle-games-addictive